# Using @media queries makes website responsive in browser, but on mobile only the full desktop version opens up

Tags: html, mobile, resize, web, responsive

I know this question has been asked before, but all suggested answers have not worked for me. I am trying to make a responsive website, and while it works just fine in the browser (when I resize it), when I open the website on my mobile device I only get the full desktop version.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>LaVida Cake</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main2.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes|Sacramento" rel="stylesheet">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
```

I made sure the `<meta>` tag is as suggested by other answers, still I don't get proper functionality on a mobile device.
Please bear with me, this is my first ever website and your help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

the css file

```
    body {
        background-image: url(pexels-photo-132694smaller.jpeg);

        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    /* **********PHONE SCREEN********** */

    @media screen and (max-width: 640px){
      #leftSide {
        display: none;
      }

      #rightside {
        display: none;
      }

      #emptyLeft {
        display: none;
      }

      #emptyRight {
        display: none;
      }

      .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-areas:
          "logo"
          "main"
          "footer";
      }

      #menu {
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
        grid-area: menu;
      }

      /* #menu ul li{
          display: inline;
          margin-right: 50px;
          font-size: 2em;
          font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
      }
      #menu ul li a {
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #d83444;
      }
      #menu ul li a:visited{
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #d83444;
          font-weight: normal;
      }
      #menu ul li a:hover {
          font-weight: bold;
      } */

      #logo {

          text-align: center;
          grid-area: logo;

      }

      #logo h1 {
        font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
        font-size: 3em;
        padding: 10px 10%;
        color: #d83444;
      }

      #main {
          text-align: center;
          grid-area: main;
          background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
          padding: 3%;
      }

      #main h1 {
          font-size: 2em;
          font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
          color: #d83444;
          letter-spacing: 7px;

      }

      #main p {
          font-size: 1.8em;
          max-width: 800px;
          margin: 20px auto;
          font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
          text-align: justify;
          color: #d83444;
      }

      #main p a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #d83444;
      }

      #main p a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #d83444;
        font-weight: normal;
      }

      #main p a:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #footer {
        grid-area: footer;
        text-align: center;
      }

      #footer ul li{

          display: inline;
          margin-right: 50px;
          font-size: 1.5em;
          font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
      }

      #footer ul li:first-child{
        display: none;
      }

      #footer ul li a {
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #d83444;
      }

      #footer ul li a:visited{
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #d83444;
          font-weight: normal;
      }

      #footer ul li a:hover {
          font-weight: bold;
      }

    }


    /* **********TABLET SCREEN********** */

    @media screen and (max-width: 959px) and (min-width: 641px){
      #leftSide {
        display: none;
      }

      #rightside {
        display: none;
      }

      .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 0.1fr 1fr 0.1fr;
        grid-template-areas:
          "emptyLeft menu emptyRight"
          "emptyLeft logo emptyRight"
          "emptyLeft main emptyRight"
          "emptyLeft footer emptyRight";
      }

      #emptyLeft {
        grid-area: emptyLeft;
      }

      #emptyRight {
        grid-area: emptyRight;
      }

      #menu {
        text-align: center;
        grid-area: menu;
      }

      #menu ul li{
          display: inline;
          margin-right: 50px;
          font-size: 2.5em;
          font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;

      }

      #menu ul li a {
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #d83444;
      }

      #menu ul li a:visited{
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #d83444;
          font-weight: normal;
      }

      #menu ul li a:hover {
          font-weight: bold;
      }

      #logo {

          text-align: center;
          grid-area: logo;

      }

      #logo h1 {
        font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
        font-size: 5em;
        letter-spacing: 7px;
        padding: 10% 10%;
        color: #d83444;
        -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
        -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(250,250,250,0.5);
      }

      #main {
          text-align: center;
          grid-area: main;
          background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
          padding: 3%;
      }

      #main h1 {
          font-size: 3em;
          font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
          color: #d83444;
          letter-spacing: 7px;

      }

      #main p {
          font-size: 2.5em;
          max-width: 800px;
          margin: 20px auto;
          font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
          text-align: justify;
          color: #d83444;
      }

      #main p a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #d83444;
      }

      #main p a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #d83444;
        font-weight: normal;
      }

      #main p a:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #footer {
        grid-area: footer;
        text-align: center;
      }

      #footer ul li{

          display: inline;
          margin-right: 50px;
          font-size: 2em;
          font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
      }

      #footer ul li a {
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #d83444;
      }

      #footer ul li a:visited{
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #d83444;
          font-weight: normal;
      }

      #footer ul li a:hover {
          font-weight: bold;
      }

    }

    /* **********FULL SCREEN********** */

    @media screen and (min-width: 959px){
      .container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2,minmax(0%,0.5fr)) minmax(300px,4fr) repeat(2,minmax(0%,0.5fr)) ;
            grid-template-areas:
                "leftSide emptyLeft menu emptyRight rightSide"
                "leftSide emptyLeft logo emptyRight rightSide"
                "leftSide emptyLeft main emptyRight rightSide"
                "leftSide footer footer footer right";

      }

      #leftSide {
        grid-area: leftSide;
      }

      #leftSide img {
        max-width: 100%;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
      }

      #leftSide img:hover {
        transform: scale(1.2);
      }

      #emptyLeft {
        grid-area: emptyLeft;
      }

      #menu {
        text-align: center;
        grid-area: menu;
      }

      #menu ul li{
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 50px;
        font-size: 3.5em;
        font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
        -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.5px;
        -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
      }

      #menu ul li :nth-of-type(3) {
        margin-right: 0;

      }

      #menu ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #d83444;
      }

      #menu ul li a:visited{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #d83444;
        font-weight: normal;
      }

      #menu ul li a:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #logo {
        text-align: center;
        grid-area: logo;

      }

      #logo h1 {
        font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
        font-size: 8em;
        padding: 10% 10%;
        color: #d83444;
        letter-spacing: 7px;
        -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1.5px;
        -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(250,250,250,0.5);
      }

      #main {
          text-align: center;
          grid-area: main;
          background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
          padding: 3%;
      }

      #main h1 {
          font-size: 4em;
          font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
          color: #d83444;
          letter-spacing: 7px;
          -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
          -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(250,250,250,0.5);
      }

      #main p {
          font-size: 3.2em;
          max-width: 800px;
          margin: 50px auto;
          font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
          text-align: justify;
          color: #d83444;
      }

      #main p a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #d83444;
      }

      #main p a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #d83444;
        font-weight: normal;
      }

      #main p a:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      hr {
         max-width: 800px;
      }

      #emptyRight {
        grid-area: emptyRight;
      }

      #rightside {
        grid-area: rightSide;
      }

      #rightside img {
          max-width: 100%;
          margin-top: 50px;
          margin-bottom: 50px;
      }

      #rightside img:hover {
          transform: scale(1.2);
      }

      #footer {
          text-align: center;
          grid-area: footer;
      }

      #footer ul li{
          display: inline;
          margin-right: 50px;
          font-size: 2.5em;
          font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
          -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.3px;
          -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
      }

      #footer ul li :nth-of-type(3) {
          margin-right: 0;
      }

      #footer ul li a {
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #d83444;
      }

  #footer ul li a:visited{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #d83444;
      font-weight: normal;
  }

  #footer ul li a:hover {
      font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

UPDATE 15 MAR 2018

I mentioned this in the comments but not in the question body itself. I am using CSS Grids for website layout. Originally I thought maybe mobile browsers don't support CSS Grids, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I'm not sure, but could it be the way my media queries are written? Meaning `min-width` and `max-width` are mixed up somehow? Does it matter what you use when viewing in different viewports?

Comment: are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: no, I 'm using CSS Grids for this. Could it be that the phone browser does not support Grids?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `CSS` framework? i.e Materialize, Bootstrap

If you are only using the `CSS` in `main2.css` then you will have to cater for each breakpoints you wan't to be responsive using **media queries**.

The `meta - viewport` tag does not make your `CSS` responsive, it lets the browser know the website is optimized for mobile.

**UPDATE**

I suggest you take a look at  [this article about responsive layouts with CSS grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Realizing_common_layouts_using_CSS_Grid_Layout). This should answer your question, will make your `CSS grids` work on mobile and desktop.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am not using Bootstrap, but I am using queries which is why it works in the browser. But I am using CSS Grids, so it just popped in my mind that maybe my mobile browser doesn't support Grids. Could you confirm this?

Comment: CSS grids work in all modern browsers, could you perhaps share your CSS with your question so I can take a look?

Comment: I just read the article you linked to. I think I did pretty much the same with my layout. I hid the side panels in the mobile and tablet version. I added the CSS file to my original post. some selectors seem to be grayed out, but I think this is just a problem when I copied the text, it works fine in the text editor.